# when rendering another view from an view containing an Iframe the view should load in the src attribute without the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dynatree

I have a Dynatree on my layout.cshtml which means the dynatre would be present on every view. Dynatree is just a tree like structure which loads data from somewhere (like a database) and the data is clickable. So when we click on an item on the tree it goes to another view. Now I have an view which contains an Iframe . What I want is whenever I click on the data Item the view should load inside the "src" attribute of the Iframe without the layout.

Any Ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `src` of an `iframe` is relatively straight-forward JavaScript 101. Create an event handler that watches for `onclick` on your Dynatree item(s), then select the `iframe` element and change the `src` attribute accordingly.

As far as removing layout goes, there's not really a built-in way to do that. Typically, you'd just add a param to the querystring of the link like `iframe`: `http://foo.com/bar?iframe`. Then, you can either branch in your action:

```
if (Request["iframe"] != null)
{
    return PartialView("_Foo");
}
else
{
    return View();
}
```

Or, in your view you can simply disable the layout:

```
@if (Request["iframe"] != null)
{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: But I do not want to return a partial view. Even if I want to that would mean for my each view I would have to create a partial view which is messy. Ok let me explain. When I click on an element on the dynatree it goes to another view . Now instead of going to another view  I just want that view to load inside the src of Iframe ofcourse without the layout

Comment: So use my second suggesrion. I gave you two options. Either will work.

Comment: Huh? No, it's just pulling the param from tge querystring out of the Request object.

Comment: ok. But stil it does only the job of nulling out the layout. How to do the other part. of putting the data in the src of iframe from the dynatree present outside

Comment: I added the querystring to the src but still the layout is coming

Comment: I tried what you said and all I am geeting now is black rectangles instead of cloured one's and the border of the iframe has also gone